# Reihenfolge im Nebensatz mit als

Tags: word-order, sentence-structure, subordinate-clause

Man hat mich gefragt, ob die Reihenfolge in dem Nebensatz ("... als hätten wir ...") richtig sei und wenn ja, warum?

> "Manchmal warten wir mit bestimmten Dingen so lange, **als hätten wir
>   noch ein zweites Leben im Koffer.**"

Warum lautet der Nebensatz nicht so:

> "... als wir noch ein zweites Leben im Koffer hätten."

Es gibt doch Nebensätze mit *als*, wo die Reihenfolge anders ist, z. B.:

> Ich war 5 Jahre alt, **als ich das erste Mal geflogen bin**.
>
> Er ist viel klüger, **als du gedacht hast**.

Es gibt bestimmt für jeden dieser Nebensätze eine Bezeichnung.

Kann mir eine(r) von euch helfen?

Answer (score 3):

Die Konjunktion „als“ kann verschiedene Funktionen haben. Je nach Funktion unterscheiden sich teilweise die Stellungen des Verbs im Nebensatz.

**Temporale Konjunktion: *als* + Endstellung des Finitums**

> Es fing an zu regnen, *als* wir das Haus *erreicht hatten.*

**Modale Konjunktion** bei Gleichheit in Sätzen, in denen ein Geschehen mit einem anderen angenommenen Geschehen verglichen wird: ***als* + Zweitstellung des Finitums**

> Er sah aus dem Fenster, *als habe* er nichts gehört.

**Modale Konjunktion** bei Gleichheit in Sätzen, in denen ein Geschehen mit einem anderen angenommenen Geschehen verglichen wird: ***als ob* + Endstellung des Finitums**

> Er sah aus dem Fenster, *als ob* er nichts gehört *habe.*

**Modale Konjunktion** bei relativischen Vergleichsbeziehungen, wenn es um Ungleichheit geht: ***als* + Endstellung des Finitums**

> Karin ist noch schöner, *als* es ihre Mutter im gleichen Alter *war.*

Answer (score 1):

Mit der Reihenfolge stimmt alles. Sieht man von den Objekten ab, ist es sogar die einzig richtige.

Es handelt sich um einen irrealen (→Konjunktiv) Vergleichssatz mit "als" als einleitender Konjunktion. In diesem Fall leitet "als" einen Stirnsatz ein, was bedeutet, dass die Personalform gleich als erste folgt:

> [...], als hätten wir noch ein zweites Leben im Koffer.
>   [...], als <strike>wir hätten</strike> noch ein zweites Leben im Koffer.
>   [...], als wir noch ein zweites Leben im Koffer <strike>hätten</strike>.

Außerdem steht unmittelbar nach der Personalform das Subjekt, wie auch in anderen Strinsätzen (die keine Fragen sind):

> Hätte ich doch bloß früher daran gedacht!
>   Gäbe es mehr davon, wäre es weniger wert.

Answer (score 1):

Bei deinen Beispielen gibt es einen großen Unterschied: Bei deinem ersten Beispiel ist der Nebensatz im Konjunktiv, bei den anderen nicht!

Dein erstes Beispiel ist soweit korrekt, aber über das "Warum?" sind sich selbst Sprachwissenschaftler nicht ganz einig (vgl. [Kapitel 3.3.1.1](http://www.gymipro.de/wiss-arbeit/zula1.pdf)). Sieh es einfach als Sonderfall an.

Die Bezeichnungen für diesen Fall sind leider sehr verschieden, die häufigsten Varianten sind irrealer oder [kontrafaktischer Vergleichs- bzw. Komparativsatz](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/sysgram.ansicht?v_typ=d&v_id=1001) (im Gegensatz zum "normalen" Vergleichs-/Komparativsatz).